# Could loin cloths be considered as a 1:1 unique item for trolls?

Tags: mythical-creatures

**Ok full backstory:**

In a post on [World Building SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/130165/41670) I asserted based on my understanding of classical troll mythology that loin clothes could be collected from dead trolls as uniquely identifiable trophies much like say scalps or heads.

**I understand that there are discrepancies between classical presentations of trolls, what I am asking is if a majority of (pre 3D games) presentations can support my assertion?**

The observations that led me to this conclusion were:

- Many troll depictions do show them wearing loin cloth like garments.
- Many depictions of troll homes depict them as primitive and sparse, no changes of clothes anywhere which allows the possibility they never change.
- Few depictions with respect to the total indicate tribal structures (communal camps, division of labor). In my opinion they seem to be somewhat solitary and occasionally come together in small groups for raids and social activities.

I feel this may lead to some argument over logic so I feel I should note that this is a mythology SE and logic of myths is irrelevant. I am asking if the stated troll mythology is inline with my underlying knowledge.